# What is the intuition for point-set topological inclusion vs topological containment?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Sets distinguish between containment and inclusion.

`A⊆B means A is included in B (subset). 
A∈B means A is contained in B (member of or element of)`

I've located this graphic depiction of topological containment:

[image]

However, looking at the points as sets, it isn't clear to me how this differs from inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The word "contains" in this case is not being used to suggest set membership. If we view graphs $G$, $X$, and $Y$ as topological spaces, then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic topological spaces, and $Y$ is a subspace of $G$: a subset of $G$ with inherited topological structure.

From the combinatorial point of view, it doesn't make much sense to think of elements or subsets: these are defined for sets, not graphs. We have the notion of a subgraph (which is similar to a subset: a subgraph of $G$ means we choose a subset of the vertices of $G$, and a subset of the edges of $G$ between them) and here, we relax that notion slightly: instead of asking for $G$ to have a subgraph isomorphic to $X$, we only ask that $G$ has a subgraph isomorphic to a subdivision of $X$.